# Displaying the data in SQL SERVER on ListBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Ive been having a hard time finding a solution for my problem, I want to display all the columns on my DB in SQL in my ListBox... anyone have an idea? please do help me?

Here is my codes:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Try
            Dim thisConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=#####;Initial Catalog=####;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=#####;Password=#####") 
            thisConnection.Open()
            Dim sql As String = ("SELECT ControlNo,EmpNo,CheckOutDate,CheckOutTime,TaxiNo,PlateNo,Model,Make FROM dbo.ChkInOut WHERE ControlNo='" & txtsearch.Text & "'")
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, thisConnection)
            da.Fill(ds, "dbo.ChkInOut")
            Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("dbo.ChkInOut")
            ListBox1.DataSource = dt
            ListBox1.DisplayMember = ("ControlNo")
            txtCtrlNo.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "ControlNo")
            txtEmpNo.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "EmpNo")
            txtCheckOutDate.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "CheckOutDate")
            txtCheckOutTime.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "CheckOutTime")
            txtTaxiUnitNo.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "TaxiNo")
            txtPlateNo.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "PlateNo")
            txtModel.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "Model")
            txtMake.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "Make")
            thisConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting `';DROP Table dbo.ChkInOut;--` into your search field. After this, the ListBox will be showing all columns still in your table.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn -- love it, hehe -- why stop there?  ';DROP DATABASE OJT;  -- SQL Injection can be fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can add multiple columns to a single listbox.  Instead, I'd recommend concatenating the column you'd like to display (`DisplayMember`) as a single column.

Perhaps something like this (assuming all columns are varchar -- if not you'll need to use `CAST`, `CONVERT` and possible `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT ControlNo + ': ' + EmpNo + ': ' + CheckOutDate + ': ' + 
          CheckOutTime + ': ' + TaxiNo + ': ' + PlateNo + ': ' + 
          Model + ': ' + Make as DisplayColumn
FROM dbo.ChkInOut 
WHERE ControlNo='" & txtsearch.Text & "'"
```

If not, you could consider using a Gridview or some other control that supports multiple columns.

BTW -- you're not setting a `ValueMember` -- you may need to do that as well depending on your needs.

Good luck.

Comment: sgeddes

these codes are working fine, my only problem is the 'LOADING TIME' can I reduce it?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question?  If you mean it takes a while to load your above query, then my only guess is you don't have an index on your ControlNo column in the DB.

Comment: yeah, it takes a while to load the result of my program...

what is that index that your talking about sir sgeddes?

Comment: In SQL Server (Management Studio), you need to make sure the table ChkInOut has and Index on the ControlNo field.  Search for SQL Server Table Indexing and you should be able to figure it out.  Easiest way is to open SSMS, right click ChkInOut table, click Design, and one of your options (on your toolbar) will be Manage Indexes and Keys -- add an index on your ControlNo field.  Google it for more information.  Good luck.

Comment: I can't find the 'Design', but I use 'Modify' and I found out there in Column Properties under Table Designer that the ControlNo (Indexable = Yes) is that it sir sgeddes?

Comment: Run something like this: CREATE INDEX IX_ChkInOut_ControlNo ON dbo.ChkInOut(ControlNo); GO -- this should create the index on the table for you :)

Comment: where to put that codes? to SQL SERVER?  or to my project in VB?

Comment: Run it in SSMS (Query Analyzer) -- it will add an index on that column.

Comment: thanks for the information sir sgeddes, I run the program again and it quite improve in terms of the loading.